# LeetCode 65: Valid Number (Python)

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, strings, regex

#### Problem

Validate if a given string can be interpreted as a decimal or scientific number.

Some examples:

```
"0" => true
" 0.1 " => true
"abc" => false
"1 a" => false
"2e10" => true
" -90e3   " => true
" 1e" => false
"e3" => false
" 6e-1" => true
" 99e2.5 " => false
"53.5e93" => true
" --6 " => false
"-+3" => false
"95a54e53" => false
```

#### Code

I've solved the valid number LeetCode problem using Python `re` module. If you'd like to review the code and provide any change/improvement recommendations, please do so and I'd really appreciate that.

```
import re
from typing import Optional    

def is_numeric(input_string: Optional[str]) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True for valid numbers and input string can be string or None
    """
    if input_string is None:
        return False

    expression_d_construct = r"^[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d+)[Ee][+-]?\d+$|^[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d+)$|^[+-]?\d+$"
    expression_char_class = r"^[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+$|^[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)$|^[+-]?[0-9]+$"

    if re.match(expression_d_construct, input_string.strip()) is not None and re.match(expression_char_class, input_string.strip()) is not None:
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
        # ---------------------------- TEST ---------------------------
    DIVIDER_DASH = '-' * 50
    GREEN_APPLE = '\U0001F34F'
    RED_APPLE = '\U0001F34E'

    test_input_strings = [None, "0  ", "0.1", "abc", "1 a", "2e10", "-90e3",
                          "1e", "e3", "6e-1", "99e2.5", "53.5e93", "--6", "-+3", "95a54e53"]

    count = 0
    for string in test_input_strings:
        print(DIVIDER_DASH)
        if is_numeric(string):
            print(f'{GREEN_APPLE} Test {int(count + 1)}: {string} is a valid number.')
        else:
            print(f'{RED_APPLE} Test {int(count + 1)}: {string} is an invalid number.')
        count += 1
```

#### Output

```
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 1: None is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 2: 0   is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 3: 0.1 is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 4: abc is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 5: 1 a is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 6: 2e10 is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 7: -90e3 is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 8: 1e is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 9: e3 is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 10: 6e-1 is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 11: 99e2.5 is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 12: 53.5e93 is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 13: --6 is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 14: -+3 is an invalid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 15: 95a54e53 is an invalid number.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/ygzjKw/1/)

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OCAFF2/1/)

If you wish to explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ygzjKw/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ygzjKw/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Source

[LeetCode Valid Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-number/)

Comment: nice apple icons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of diving into cumbersome and lengthy regex expressions consider the following improvement/correction:

The main thesis for the underlying aspect is:

> Numeric literals containing a decimal point or an *exponent* sign
>   yield **floating** point numbers.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex

Therefore Python treats values like `53.5e93`, `-90e3` as float type numbers.

Eventually I would proceed with the following approach (retaining those cute icons) including additional small optimizations:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Optional


def is_numeric(input_string: Optional[str]) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True for valid numbers. Acceptable types of items: str or None
    """
    if input_string is None:
        return False

    try:
        input_string = input_string.strip()
        float(input_string)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # ---------------------------- TEST ---------------------------
    DIVIDER_DASH = '-' * 50
    GREEN_APPLE = '\U0001F34F'
    RED_APPLE = '\U0001F34E'

    test_input_strings = [None, "0  ", "0.1", "abc", "1 a", "2e10", "-90e3",
                          "1e", "e3", "6e-1", "99e2.5", "53.5e93", "--6", "-+3", "95a54e53"]

    count = 0
    for string in test_input_strings:
        print(DIVIDER_DASH)
        count += 1

        if is_numeric(string):
            print(f'{GREEN_APPLE} Test {count}: `{string}` is a valid number.')
        else:
            print(f'{RED_APPLE} Test {count}: `{string}` is not a valid number.')
```

The output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 1: `None` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 2: `0  ` is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 3: `0.1` is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 4: `abc` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 5: `1 a` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 6: `2e10` is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 7: `-90e3` is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 8: `1e` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 9: `e3` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 10: `6e-1` is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 11: `99e2.5` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 12: `53.5e93` is a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 13: `--6` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 14: `-+3` is not a valid number.
--------------------------------------------------
 Test 15: `95a54e53` is not a valid number.
```

Comment: The `.strip()` part is not necessary, because python allows optional leading and trailing whitespace. Also, you can omit the `None` check and catch both `ValueError`  and `TypeError`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just go with @Roman's suggestion. You should just leave it up to the language to decide what is and isn't valid.

I'd make two further suggestions though:

I don't think the parameter to `is_numeric` should be `Optional`; either conceptually, or to comply with the challenge. `None` will never be a valid number, so why even check it? I don't think dealing with invalid data should be that function's responsibility. Make it take just a `str`, then deal with `None`s externally. I also don't really think it's `is_numeric`'s responsibility to be dealing with trimming either; and that isn't even required:

```
print(float(" 0.1 "))  # prints 0.1
```

I'd also `return True` from within the `try`. The behavior will be the same, but I find it makes it clearer the intent of the `try`.

After the minor changes, I'd go with:

```
def is_numeric(input_string: str) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True for valid numbers. Acceptable types of items: str or None
    """
    try:
        parsed = float(input_string)
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False

if string is not None and is_numeric(string):
    print(f'{GREEN_APPLE} Test {count}: `{string}` is a valid number.')
else:
    print(f'{RED_APPLE} Test {count}: `{string}` is not a valid number.')
```

Answer (score 1):

That regex visualisation you provided is really neat. It shows that there is a lot of potential overlap in the conditions.

You should be able to reduce it down to something similar to this:

```
^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([Ee][+-]?\d+)?$
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `1.` or `.5`, both of which are matched by the regex in the OP. Your regex assumes that there will always be a leading digit before a period, and that a period will always be followed by decimals. Neither is true.