# LeetCode 65: Valid Number (C++)

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, strings, regex

#### Problem

Validate if a given string can be interpreted as a decimal or scientific number.

#### Examples:

```
"0" => true
" 0.1 " => true
"abc" => false
"1 a" => false
"2e10" => true
" -90e3   " => true
" 1e" => false
"e3" => false
" 6e-1" => true
" 99e2.5 " => false
"53.5e93" => true
" --6 " => false
"-+3" => false
"95a54e53" => false
```

#### Code

With some help, I've solved the valid number LeetCode problem using C++ regex and [Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230848/leetcode-65-valid-number-python), which apparently seems to have a simple solution though. If you'd like to review the code and provide any change/improvement recommendations, please do so and I'd really appreciate that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex> 

using namespace std;

// trim from start (in place)
static inline void ltrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int ch) {
        return !std::isspace(ch);
    }));
}

// trim from end (in place)
static inline void rtrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](int ch) {
        return !std::isspace(ch);
    }).base(), s.end());
}

// trim from both ends (in place)
static inline void trim(std::string &s) {
    ltrim(s);
    rtrim(s);
}

// trim from start (copying)
static inline std::string ltrim_copy(std::string s) {
    ltrim(s);
    return s;
}

// trim from end (copying)
static inline std::string rtrim_copy(std::string s) {
    rtrim(s);
    return s;
}

// trim from both ends (copying)
static inline std::string trim_copy(std::string s) {
    trim(s);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> string_vector = {
        "   0  ","   0.1   ","  abc  ",
        "1 a","   2e10   ","  -90e3 ","1e",
        "  e3  ","  6e-1  ","  99e2.5   ",
        " 53.5e93 "," --6 ","  -+3  ",
        "   95a54e53  "
    };

    regex expression_one("^[+-]?(?:\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*|\\d+)[Ee][+-]?\\d+$|^[+-]?(?:\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*|\\d+)$|^[+-]?\\d+$");
    regex expression_two("^[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+$|^[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)$|^[+-]?[0-9]+$");
    regex expression_three("^(?:(?:[+-]?(?:\\d*[.]\\d+|\\d+[.]\\d*|\\d+)[Ee][+-]?\\d+)|(?:[+-]?(?:\\d*[.]\\d+|\\d+[.]\\d*|\\d+))|[+-]?\\d+)$");

    for (const auto &input_string: string_vector) {
        auto trim_input_string = trim_copy(input_string);
        if (std::regex_match(trim_input_string, expression_two))
            cout << "1️⃣ Test Expression 1: '" << input_string << "' is a valid number." << endl;
        if (std::regex_match(trim_input_string, expression_two))
            cout << "2️⃣ Test Expression 2: '" << input_string << "' is a valid number." << endl;
        if (std::regex_match(trim_input_string, expression_two))
            cout << "3️⃣ Test Expression 3: '" << input_string << "' is a valid number." << endl;

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
1️⃣ Test Expression 1: '   0  ' is a valid number.
2️⃣ Test Expression 2: '   0  ' is a valid number.
3️⃣ Test Expression 3: '   0  ' is a valid number.
1️⃣ Test Expression 1: '   0.1   ' is a valid number.
2️⃣ Test Expression 2: '   0.1   ' is a valid number.
3️⃣ Test Expression 3: '   0.1   ' is a valid number.
1️⃣ Test Expression 1: '   2e10   ' is a valid number.
2️⃣ Test Expression 2: '   2e10   ' is a valid number.
3️⃣ Test Expression 3: '   2e10   ' is a valid number.
1️⃣ Test Expression 1: '  -90e3 ' is a valid number.
2️⃣ Test Expression 2: '  -90e3 ' is a valid number.
3️⃣ Test Expression 3: '  -90e3 ' is a valid number.
1️⃣ Test Expression 1: '  6e-1  ' is a valid number.
2️⃣ Test Expression 2: '  6e-1  ' is a valid number.
3️⃣ Test Expression 3: '  6e-1  ' is a valid number.
1️⃣ Test Expression 1: ' 53.5e93 ' is a valid number.
2️⃣ Test Expression 2: ' 53.5e93 ' is a valid number.
3️⃣ Test Expression 3: ' 53.5e93 ' is a valid number.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/ygzjKw/1/)

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OCAFF2/1/)

If you wish to explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ygzjKw/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ygzjKw/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Source

- [LeetCode Valid Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-number/)
- [LeetCode 65: Valid Number (Python)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230848/leetcode-65-valid-number-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Don't do `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- `inline` is really only useful for defining non-template functions in header files. Modern compilers generally decide what functions to actually inline themselves.
- To [use `std::isspace` correctly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) we must cast the argument from a `char` to an `unsigned char` before passing it into the function.
- `std::regex_match` has a version that takes iterators. So we don't need to copy or modify the input strings:

  ```
  auto const is_not_space = [] (unsigned char c) {
      return std::isspace(c) == 0;
  };

  for (auto const& s: string_vector) {
      auto const begin = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_not_space);
      auto const end = std::find_if(s.rbegin(), std::reverse_iterator(begin), is_not_space).base();

      if (std::regex_match(begin, end, expression_two))
          ...
  ```
- The test code checks `expression_two` three times, and doesn't use `expression_one` or `expression_three`!